# Returning specific array object within a method definition

Tags: java, arrays

I need to determine which predator in my `PredatorList` array has received the most damage. For some reason when I try to return that predator, eclipse says - `mostDamaged` cannot be resolved to a variable.

Why is this so?

```
public Predator mostDamagedPredator() {
    // test if PredatorList contains predators
    if (PredatorList.length > 0){
        float difference = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < PredatorList.length; i++) {
            if (PredatorList[i].getMaxHitPoints() - PredatorList[i].getHitPoints() > difference){
                Predator mostDamaged = PredatorList[i];
            }
        }
        return mostDamaged;  // ERROR - mostDamaged cannot be resolved to a variable
    }
    // return null if there are no predators in PredatorList
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Because there isn't a variable called `mostDamaged`.

Comment: Incidentally this can all be written as `Arrays.stream(PredatorList).max(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getMaxHitPoints() - p.getHitPoints()))`. Further, in Java we use `camelCase` for variables, `PascalCase` is reserves for classes - please **always** stick to this convention.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `mostDamaged` inside an `if` statement block, so it's not within scope outside that block.

Move it outside :

```
public Predator mostDamagedPredator() {
    if (PredatorList.length > 0){
        float difference = 0;
        Predator mostDamaged = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < PredatorList.length; i++) {
            if (PredatorList[i].getMaxHitPoints() - PredatorList[i].getHitPoints() > difference){
                mostDamaged = PredatorList[i];
            }
        }
        return mostDamaged; 
    }
    return null;
}
```

or a little better :

```
public Predator mostDamagedPredator() {
    Predator mostDamaged = null;
    if (PredatorList.length > 0){
        float difference = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < PredatorList.length; i++) {
            if (PredatorList[i].getMaxHitPoints() - PredatorList[i].getHitPoints() > difference){
                mostDamaged = PredatorList[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return mostDamaged;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but my `mostDamaged` variable in the if statement becomes a duplicate local variable and so when i return `mostDamaged`, it returns null.

Comment: @BobSacamano Please note you don't need to re-declare `mostDamaged` inside the if statement, just assign to it. See the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared mostDamaged variable inside for context.

Declare it out, and initialize it there:

```
public Predator mostDamagedPredator() {
// test if PredatorList contains predators
if (PredatorList.length > 0){
    float difference = 0;
    Predator mostDamaged = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < PredatorList.length; i++) {
        if (PredatorList[i].getMaxHitPoints() - PredatorList[i].getHitPoints() > difference){
            mostDamaged = PredatorList[i];
        }
    }
    return mostDamaged;  // ERROR - mostDamaged cannot be resolved to a variable
}
// return null if there are no predators in PredatorList
return null;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is because `mostDamaged` is defined within the `if` statement of your `for` loop. This means where you want to return it the variable is not defined.

You can rewrite the method like this:

```
public Predator mostDamagedPredator() {
    // test if PredatorList contains predators
    Predator mostDamaged = null; // initialize it with null
    if (PredatorList.length > 0){
        float difference = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < PredatorList.length; i++) {
            if (PredatorList[i].getMaxHitPoints() - PredatorList[i].getHitPoints() > difference){
                mostDamaged = PredatorList[i]; // assign the correct item from the array
            }
        }
    }
    // either mostDamaged was initialized in the if statement or it is still null
    return mostDamaged;
}
```